# How to apply youtube embed code (If string is youtube url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have tried to apply the embed code from youtube url and everything work fine.
But I want to find the solution if the string is not youtube link, then do not apply embed code.

**Here is my code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.youtube').html(function(i,v){

    var id = v.split('watch?v=')[1]; // get the id so you can add to iframe
    return '<iframe width="490" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id +"?wmode=opaque"+ '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
});
});
```

I realy don´t know how to do that ? Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a conditional looking for an index of 'watch?v=' before running your split function.

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.youtube').html(function(i,v){
        // check for an instance of 'watch?v='
        if (v.indexOf('watch?v=') !== -1) {
            var id = v.split('watch?v=')[1]; // get the id so you can add to iframe
            return '<iframe width="490" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id +"?wmode=opaque"+ '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        } else {
            // return full url as string if not a youtube
            return v;
        }
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: if the youtube vid have `&list=` or other stuff this will probably fail, I would further split by `&` then take the left part of it with `[0]`